# "redirect" packages

Tags: java, android

Is there a way to "redirect" packages?

Is there any possibility to tell Android to get the class-files from e.g. `com.java.rmi` instead of `java.rmi`?

Some additional libraries depend on this package so I repacked it with jarjar - otherwise dalvik-exc would occur.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `import` statements. If you are using Eclipse, you can just remove the `java.rmi` import lines and press <kbd>Control-Shift-O</kbd> (Organize Imports). It will ask you which package to import.

**Edit:** yes, you have to do this in all files that use said package.

Comment: i was already thinking of that but i cant edit the imports inside of a jar :/